# run scripts with option minus c

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, jboss

I have seen several scripts that use the -c option, what is the meaning of this -c option?
For example:
/opt/jboss/bin/standalone.sh -c standalone.xml
I would like to know what is the difference between executing this command with the option minus c and without it:
/opt/jboss/bin/standalone.sh standalone.xml

Comment: It's *totally* up to the script. Each of the several scripts you've seen may interpret `-c` in its own way. There is an answer for the specific `standalone.sh` from your example, but not in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shell scripts and command-line tools define their own options. The same character/option means different things for different utilities, simply because they do different things. As an example, `grep` uses `-c` for counting matches. `ls` uses `-c` to sort files by the 'ctime' parameter. `less` uses `-c` to specify a 'clear screen' setting. The only reliable way to determine what an option does (or if it is even a valid option) is to refer to the tool's/script's documentation. Most command-line utilities come with manuals or manpages. Script documentation is usually included as comments inside the script itself.

The specific script you are referring to is a startup script for JBoss Application Server (also known as JBoss Enterprise Application Platform, or its upstream source, WildFly). In this context, `-c` specifies the configuration file used to start the server. JBoss AS specifies all of the server configuration in a single XML file. The distribution comes with multiple variations of the file, such as standalone.xml, standalone-full.xml, standalone-ha.xml etc. Each of these files configure the server in different ways.

To use a specific configuration file, you use the `-c` option as `standalone.sh -c=standalone-full.xml`. When it is not specified, it defaults to standalone.xml

Reference to the relevant WildFly documentation: https://docs.wildfly.org/26/Admin_Guide.html#configuration-files

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, that would be variable that points to configuration file.

View the scripts source to see what it exactly points to, or run

`scriptname --help`

to get the variable explanations.